# Merging 2 lists (not using pandas)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to do an inner join with 2 lists in python, without using pandas or numpy libraries.

The function combine has parameters:
One: first list; Two: second list; left: indice of column in first list; right: indice of column in second list

I am trying to combine the 2 lists based on the indices of each list having elements that equal and then joining their elements together.

So far I have this code:

```
def combine(one, two, left, right):
    combined = []
    for x in one:                         #for elements in list one
        for y in two:                     #for elements in list two
            if x[left] == y[right]:       #if both elements at each indice equal
                combined = [x,y]          #place x and y values into combined list

    print(combined)


one = [['apple', 'fruit'],
       ['broccoli', 'vegetable']]
two = [['fruit', '1'],
       ['vegetable', '1']]

combine(one, two, 1, 0 )
```

For some reason i am getting an empty list:  []

The desired output is:

```
 [['apple', 'fruit', 'fruit', '1'],
 ['broccoli', 'vegetable', 'vegetable', '1']]
```

Any ideas/tips of how i can accomplish this?

Comment: your indices are wrong. left index should be 1

Comment: from `one`: `'apple' != 'fruit'` or `'vegetable'`. similar for `two`. try `combine(one, two, 1, 0)`, but you'll need to change `combined = [x,y]` to `combined.append(x + y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this code helps!

```
def combine(one, two, left, right):
    combined = []
    for x in one:  #for elements in list one
        for y in two:  #for elements in list two
            if x[left] == y[right]:  #if both elements at each indice equal
                combined.append(
                    x + y)  #place x and y values into combined list

    print(combined)


one = [['apple', 'fruit'], ['broccoli', 'vegetable']]
two = [['fruit', '1'], ['vegetable', '1']]

combine(one, two, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, you should be calling the function like this:

```
combine(one, two, 1, 0 )
```

Since the position one[1] is the one that has the common value with two[0].